# Android: failed to Display jsonobject into a listView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listview-adapter

Im developping an  android application with android studio , the application is consuming a restful web service, i cant to display a result into my a listView , but when i tried it i alwayes get a list view that contains i think adresses i got this format:

```
com.example.projetmonitoringapplication.listez$Dabl@d593975
```

notice that i've got 4 elemnts as the result resturns , in my log i can see that i get objects and i even can get an element from the ArrayList.
i think that the problem is on the adapter or i dont know , can someone tell me what to do please .

i tried two things an arrayAdapter that returns that result and a normal adapter that returns an empty listview.
you can see that on my code

this the Activity , i tried many things even the code in the comments:

```
   package com.example.projetmonitoringapplication;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpGet;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Created by Emel on 24/04/2017.
 */

public class listez extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myListView;   // BaseAdapter2 adapter;
   ArrayList<Dabl> arrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<Dabl>();
    //this is our result object

    class Dabl {
        int id ;
        String libdab;
        String etat;
        String des ;
        String zone ;

        public Dabl() {
            super();
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getLibdab() {
            return libdab;
        }

        public void setLibdab(String libdab) {
            this.libdab = libdab;
        }

        public String getEtat() {
            return etat;
        }

        public void setEtat(String etat) {
            this.etat = etat;
        }

        public String getDes() {
            return des;
        }

        public void setDes(String des) {
            this.des = des;
        }

        public String getZone() {
            return zone;
        }

        public void setZone(String zone) {
            this.zone = zone;
        }

        public Dabl(int id, String libdab, String etat, String des, String zone) {
            this.id = id;
            this.libdab = libdab;
            this.etat = etat;
            this.des = des;
            this.zone = zone;
        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listezonelayout);
      //  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstdab);
        new TheTask().execute();
       /* ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstdab);
        Dabl d= new Dabl(3,"gg","hh","uu","xx");
        arrayOfWebData.add(d);
        ArrayAdapter<Dabl> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dabl>(listez.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayOfWebData );
        myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);*/


       //String s =myListView.getItemAtPosition(1).toString();

        //Log.e("element ", s);
    }
    adapter aa ;

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String str = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(
                        "http://10.0.2.2:8180/ProjetMonitoring/RestApp/DA/RechercherDABzTunis");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.e("test", "----" + str);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return str;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);


                String response = result.toString();
                try {


                    //JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    //  Log.i("result  ",result.toString()+" res1");

                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0, count = jArray.length(); i < count; i++) {
                        String string = jArray.getString(i);

                        //get our object, this is one person's worth of data
                        //  JSONObject json_data=new JSONObject(result.toString().substring(result.indexOf("{"), result.toString().lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(string);

                        // JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Log.i("json data  ",json_data.toString()+"  jjj");
                        int id = json_data.getInt("id_DAB");
                        String libdab = json_data.getString("Libelle_DAB");
                        String etat = json_data.getString("etat");
                        String des= json_data.getString("description");
                        String zone= json_data.getString("zone");
                        Log.d("Success", "id: " + id + "\nlibdab: " + libdab + "\netat: " + etat +
                                "\ndes: " + des + "\nzone: " + zone);
                        Log.i("result2  ", String.valueOf(id));

                      //  Dabl resultRow = new Dabl(id,libdab,etat,des,zone);

                        Dabl resultRow = new Dabl(id,libdab,etat,des,zone);

                  resultRow.setId( json_data.getInt("id_DAB"));
                    resultRow.setLibdab( json_data.getString("Libelle_DAB"));
                    resultRow.setEtat( json_data.getString("etat"));
                    resultRow.setDes( json_data.getString("description"));
                    resultRow.setZone(json_data.getString("zone"));

                        arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
                    Log.i("zone",arrayOfWebData.get(0).getZone()+" get");

                }
                ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstdab);

                aa=new adapter();

               myListView.setAdapter(aa);
                //String s=myListView.getItemAtPosition(1).toString();
               // Log.i("ITEM",s);
                 //   lis(  arrayOfWebData);
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        /*public void lis( ArrayList<Dabl> arrayOfWebData){
        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstdab);
        ArrayAdapter<Dabl> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dabl>(listez.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfWebData);
         myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);}*/
    }


    class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Dabl> {
        adapter() {
            super(listez.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfWebData);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView==null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listdabzitem, null);

                holder=new listez.ViewHolder(convertView);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
           else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));

            return(convertView);
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView idd;
        public TextView lib;
        public TextView et;
        public TextView des;
        public TextView zone;

        ViewHolder(View row) {
            idd=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.id);
            lib=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.libdab);
            et=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tet);
            des=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.libe);
            zone=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.zone);
        }
        void populateFrom(Dabl r) {
            idd.setText(r.getId());
            lib.setText(r.getLibdab());
            et.setText(r.getEtat());
            des.setText(r.getDes());
            zone.setText(r.getZone());
        }
    }

}
```

and in i have two layouts one that contains a listview the other contains the elements of the list View :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/libdab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/libe"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="La liste des DAB" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstdab"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my log you can see that i cna get the objects from my WS:

```
04-26 17:06:11.998 5274-5274/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-26 17:06:11.998 5274-5274/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
04-26 17:06:12.118 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication-2/lib/x86
04-26 17:06:12.171 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed

                                                                                       [ 04-26 17:06:12.172  5274: 5274 D/         ]
                                                                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa594af80, tid 5274


                                                                                       [ 04-26 17:06:12.256  5274: 5291 D/         ]
                                                                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa28ff580, tid 5291
04-26 17:06:12.266 5274-5291/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-26 17:06:12.266 5274-5291/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-26 17:06:12.267 5274-5291/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-26 17:06:12.267 5274-5291/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
04-26 17:06:15.290 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-26 17:06:15.395 5274-5344/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
04-26 17:06:15.876 5274-5291/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xa28f8580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x968610b0
04-26 17:06:16.019 5274-5344/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication E/test: ----["{\"zone\":\"Tunis\",\"description\":\"le DAB fonctionne correctement.\",\"id_DAB\":22,\"etat\":\"En marche\",\"Libelle_DAB\":\"\"}","{\"zone\":\"Tunis\",\"description\":\"le DAB fonctionne correctement.\",\"id_DAB\":26,\"etat\":\"En marche\",\"Libelle_DAB\":\"ooo\"}","{\"zone\":\"Tunis\",\"description\":\"le DAB fonctionne correctement.\",\"id_DAB\":27,\"etat\":\"En marche\",\"Libelle_DAB\":\"\"}","{\"zone\":\"Tunis\",\"description\":\"le DAB fonctionne correctement.\",\"id_DAB\":6660,\"etat\":\"En marche\",\"Libelle_DAB\":\"yyy\"}"]
04-26 17:06:16.022 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/json data: {"zone":"Tunis","description":"le DAB fonctionne correctement.","id_DAB":22,"etat":"En marche","Libelle_DAB":""}  jjj
04-26 17:06:16.022 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication D/Success: id: 22
                                                                                libdab: 
                                                                                etat: En marche
                                                                                des: le DAB fonctionne correctement.
                                                                                zone: Tunis
04-26 17:06:16.022 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/result2: 22
04-26 17:06:16.022 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/zone: Tunis get
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/json data: {"zone":"Tunis","description":"le DAB fonctionne correctement.","id_DAB":26,"etat":"En marche","Libelle_DAB":"ooo"}  jjj
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication D/Success: id: 26
                                                                                libdab: ooo
                                                                                etat: En marche
                                                                                des: le DAB fonctionne correctement.
                                                                                zone: Tunis
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/result2: 26
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/zone: Tunis get
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/json data: {"zone":"Tunis","description":"le DAB fonctionne correctement.","id_DAB":27,"etat":"En marche","Libelle_DAB":""}  jjj
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication D/Success: id: 27
                                                                                libdab: 
                                                                                etat: En marche
                                                                                des: le DAB fonctionne correctement.
                                                                                zone: Tunis
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/result2: 27
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/zone: Tunis get
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/json data: {"zone":"Tunis","description":"le DAB fonctionne correctement.","id_DAB":6660,"etat":"En marche","Libelle_DAB":"yyy"}  jjj
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication D/Success: id: 6660
                                                                                libdab: yyy
                                                                                etat: En marche
                                                                                des: le DAB fonctionne correctement.
                                                                                zone: Tunis
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/result2: 6660
04-26 17:06:16.023 5274-5274/com.example.projetmonitoringapplication I/zone: Tunis get
```

the activity code contains many methods , dont worry about that i just tried many things and all of these codes sheet didn't workd .

Comment: actually, you are passing the first index of a list instead of a list.(List<Dabl>) arrayOfWebData.get(0).

Comment: Also check  whether the adapter get view funciton is tiggered or not.

Comment: @Vishwa actually i only wrote this to try if i can get an element but it didn't work , basacly its 
(listez.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  arrayOfWebDat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is the solution ! hope t will help someone

```
package com.example.projetmonitoringapplication;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpGet;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Created by Emel on 24/04/2017.
 */

public class listez extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myListView;   // BaseAdapter2 adapter;
   ArrayList<Dabl> arrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<Dabl>();
    //this is our result object

    class Dabl {
        int id ;
        String libdab;
        String etat;
        String des ;
        String zone ;

        public Dabl() {
            super();
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getLibdab() {
            return libdab;
        }

        public void setLibdab(String libdab) {
            this.libdab = libdab;
        }

        public String getEtat() {
            return etat;
        }

        public void setEtat(String etat) {
            this.etat = etat;
        }

        public String getDes() {
            return des;
        }

        public void setDes(String des) {
            this.des = des;
        }

        public String getZone() {
            return zone;
        }

        public void setZone(String zone) {
            this.zone = zone;
        }

        public Dabl(int id, String libdab, String etat, String des, String zone) {
            this.id = id;
            this.libdab = libdab;
            this.etat = etat;
            this.des = des;
            this.zone = zone;
        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listezonelayout);
      //  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstdab);
        new TheTask().execute();
       /* ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstdab);
        Dabl d= new Dabl(3,"gg","hh","uu","xx");
        arrayOfWebData.add(d);
        ArrayAdapter<Dabl> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dabl>(listez.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayOfWebData );
        myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);*/


       //String s =myListView.getItemAtPosition(1).toString();

        //Log.e("element ", s);
    }
    adapter aa ;

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String str = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(
                        "http://10.0.2.2:8180/ProjetMonitoring/RestApp/DA/RechercherDABzTunis");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.e("test", "----" + str);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return str;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);


                String response = result.toString();
                try {


                    //JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    //  Log.i("result  ",result.toString()+" res1");

                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0, count = jArray.length(); i < count; i++) {
                        String string = jArray.getString(i);

                        //get our object, this is one person's worth of data
                        //  JSONObject json_data=new JSONObject(result.toString().substring(result.indexOf("{"), result.toString().lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(string);

                        // JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Log.i("json data  ",json_data.toString()+"  jjj");
                        int id = json_data.getInt("id_DAB");
                        String libdab = json_data.getString("Libelle_DAB");
                        String etat = json_data.getString("etat");
                        String des= json_data.getString("description");
                        String zone= json_data.getString("zone");
                        Log.d("Success", "id: " + id + "\nlibdab: " + libdab + "\netat: " + etat +
                                "\ndes: " + des + "\nzone: " + zone);
                        Log.i("result2  ", String.valueOf(id));

                      //  Dabl resultRow = new Dabl(id,libdab,etat,des,zone);

                        Dabl resultRow = new Dabl(id,libdab,etat,des,zone);

                  resultRow.setId( json_data.getInt("id_DAB"));
                    resultRow.setLibdab( json_data.getString("Libelle_DAB"));
                    resultRow.setEtat( json_data.getString("etat"));
                    resultRow.setDes( json_data.getString("description"));
                    resultRow.setZone(json_data.getString("zone"));

                        arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
                    Log.i("zone",arrayOfWebData.get(0).getZone()+" get");

                }
                ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstdab);

                aa=new adapter();

                myListView.setAdapter(aa);
                //String s=myListView.getItemAtPosition(1).toString();
               // Log.i("ITEM",s);
                 //   lis(  arrayOfWebData);
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        /*public void lis( ArrayList<Dabl> arrayOfWebData){
        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstdab);
        ArrayAdapter<Dabl> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dabl>(listez.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfWebData);
         myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);}*/
    }


    class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Dabl> {
        adapter() {
            super(listez.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfWebData);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView==null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listdabzitem, null);

                holder=new listez.ViewHolder(convertView);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
           else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));

            return(convertView);
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView idd;
        public TextView lib;
        public TextView et;
        public TextView des;
        public TextView zone;

        ViewHolder(View row) {
            idd=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.id);
            lib=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.libdab);
            et=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tet);
            des=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.libe);
            zone=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.zone);
        }
        void populateFrom(Dabl r) {
            idd.setText(String.valueOf(r.getId()));
            lib.setText(r.getLibdab());
            et.setText(r.getEtat());
            des.setText(r.getDes());
            zone.setText(r.getZone());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not getting data in listview is you are trying to assign the ArrayList to default array adapter instead of your adapter.

Moreover, it is not a standard way to place adapter and asyncTask within an activity.It's better to create separate java files for adapter and async task.

Let's come to code.

In adapter, it's always recommended to pass context, layout and ArrayList for better readability.

**In adapter**

place this code

```
    Context context;
    ArrayList<listez.Dabl> list;
    adapter(Context context,int resId,ArrayList<listez.Dabl> list) {
        super(context, resId, list);
        this.context=context;
        this.list=list;
    }
```

instead of

```
  adapter() {
        super(listez.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfWebData);
    }
```

and also within **Adapter class populateFrom function**

you are trying to show integer in textview. It may raise an error.

place this

```
 idd.setText(String.valueOf(r.getId()));
```

instead of

```
 idd.setText(r.getId());
```

**In AsyncTask onPost execute function**

place this code at last  after adding data to ArrayList

```
  list( ArrayList<Dabl> arrayOfWebData);
```

then insert this function in **listez class**

```
    public void list( ArrayList<Dabl> arrayOfWebData){
        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstdab);
        adapter arrayAdapter = new adapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayOfWebData );
        myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: thank you vishwa i updated my code i used the adpter only and the proble was the idd.setText! thanks for your help , chek the updated code if you want , this code works.